# Plain integer equation numbers (without chapter prefix) that resets on every new chapter with correct eqref/hyperref behavior for them

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, counters, ref

My code:

```tex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}
\begin{equation}
  \label{a}
  1 + 1 = 2.
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  \label{b}
  2 + 2 = 4.
\end{equation}

\chapter{Elementary Results}
\begin{equation}
  \label{c}
  10 + 10 = 20.
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  \label{d}
  20 + 20 = 40.
\end{equation}

From \eqref{c} and \eqref{d} we get

\begin{equation}
  30 + 30 = 60.
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Here is how the document layout looks:

- Chapter 1

  - Equation 1.1
  - Equation 1.2
- Chapter 2

  - Equation 2.1
  - Equation 2.2
  - Two links to equations 2.1 and 2.2
  - Equation 2.3

What I want instead:

- Chapter 1

  - Equation 1
  - Equation 2
- Chapter 2

  - Equation 1
  - Equation 2
  - Two links to equations 1 and 2 of the current chapter (chapter 2)
  - Equation 3

Can this be achieved in LaTeX?

Comment: Have you tried `\renewcommand\theequation{\arabic{equation}`?

Comment: How do you plan to reference equations in other chapters?

Comment: As long as each equation gets a unique label, there should be no problems with hyperlinking.  (Only possibly confusion for someone reading on paper. who isn't able to hyperlink.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you're using the `book` document class, running

```
\renewcommand\theequation{\arabic{equation}
```

in the preamble is really all you need to apply to your test code in order to achieve your formatting objectives.

The following screenshot shows the output of the chapter-2 test material. You may verify easily that the cross-references "(1)" and "(2)" point to the equations on that page rather than at, say, the sample equations associated with chapter 1.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\renewcommand\theequation{\arabic{equation}} % <-- new
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink,noabbrev]{cleveref}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}
\begin{gather}
  1 + 1 = 2. \label{a} \\
  2 + 2 = 4. \label{b}
\end{gather}

\chapter{Elementary Results}
\begin{gather}
  10 + 10 = 20.  \label{c} \\
  20 + 20 = 40.  \label{d}
\end{gather}
From \labelcref{c,d} we get
\begin{equation}
  30 + 30 = 60.
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```